# Row Number in mysql not working from Java

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

I have a query like below, which contains implemented row number

```
 select   @running:=if(@previous= concat(inouts.days,inouts.element_id,
    inouts.slot_id),@running,0) + 1 as rownum,
    @previous:=concat(inouts.days,inouts.element_id,inouts.slot_id),
    element_value,element_id,date_time,slot_id,days   
    from in_out_element_entry inouts where id_number='1234'
    and element_id>12   
    order by days,element_id,slot_id,date_time
```

This returns result as shown in the image attached:

```
rownum | @previous....|element_value|element_id|  date_time         |time_slot  |days  |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1      |  ...         |  30         |    21    |2013-10-09 14:33:26 |   25      |  0
1      |  ...         |  30         |    21    |2013-10-09 14:33:26 |   25      |  0
2      |  ...         |  30         |    21    |2013-10-09 14:33:40 |   25      |  0
1      |  ...         |  130        |    22    |2013-10-09 14:33:26 |   25      |  0
2      |  ...         |  130        |    22    |2013-10-09 14:33:40 |   25      |  0
1      |  ...         |  900        |    23    |2013-10-09 14:33:26 |   26      |  0
2      |  ...         |  900        |    23    |2013-10-09 14:33:40 |   26      |  0
```

But when I try to run this query using the JDBC , All the row numbers are 1 .

I even tried executing same query via a stored procedure. And called the SP from the Java Dao class.
But eventhen the results change. All the rownumber column become 1.

I have no idea what to do or why it is happenning. Can anybody help?

I create a Stored Procedure like this:

```
    create or replace procedure sp_in_out_report(
IN p_id_number VARCHAR(45))
begin
start transaction ;
insert into r_in_out(id_number,days,total_in)  
 select p_ip_number,days,sum(element_value) as total_in from
 (select   @running:=if(@previous= concat(inouts.days,inouts.element_id,
        inouts.slot_id),@running,0) + 1 as rownum,
        @previous:=concat(inouts.days,inouts.element_id,inouts.slot_id),
        element_value,element_id,date_time,slot_id,days   
        from in_out_element_entry inouts where id_number=p_id_number
        and element_id>12   
        order by days,element_id,slot_id,date_time )where rownum=1 group by days
commit;
end
```

Then call from Java as shown :

```
CallableStatement callableStatement = null;

String procedureCall = "{call sp_ins_out_summary_report(?)}";

callableStatement = connection.prepareCall(procedureCall);
callableStatement.setString("p_id_number", idNum);
callableStatement.executeUpdate();
```

Basically Ill need row Number to get latest value of a any element_id from each slot according to the date_time

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for editing. I couldnt upload the image :-)

Comment: please share the java code, and why do you need row number generally?!

Comment: Ill edit the question again with two more POCs

Comment: Here is why I need row number for:
I have to sum up all the values with element id >12 , All values being the latest in their slot of a particular day. So, Ill get row number 1,2,3... so on for one time slot with that particular element_id of that day.